# ExtJs: destroy window

Tags: extjs

In ExtJs how to handle such scenario Window A has grid A which routes to pop up window B after clicking on hyperlink A.
 window B has a panel with another hyperlink B which  render some data on Window A.

after clicking hyperlink B data gets properly rendered on window A. But window B ( from where hyperlink got clicked) does not get destroy.

How to destroy window B once hyperlink renders data.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where your problem is.

```
var window = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {width:200, height:200});
window.show();
console.log(window.getWidth());
window.close();
console.log(window.getWidth()); // throws error because window is destroyed
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21id

If you like to do it more explicitly, you can always call [`destroy`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.window.Window.html#method-destroy) on the window.